# How to change NA as a missing value indicator?

Tags: r, na

I have some factor values indicating circulation patterns:

```
BM HB HFA HFZ HM HNA HNFA HNFZ HNZ NEA NEZ NWA NWZ NA NZ SA SEA SEZ SWA SWZ SZ TB TM TRM TRW U WA WS WW WZ
```

One of the factor, is circulation pattern called `NA`. 
When I used that data, R interpret `NA` pattern as a missing value. Is there a way to say to R that `NA` is a proper value?

Here is some data sample:

```
   df <- structure(list(data = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(21L, 
    21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L), mon = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = 46:55, wday = c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L), yday = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 
    20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", 
"mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", 
"POSIXt")), gwl = structure(c(4L, NA, 24L, 14L, 4L, 14L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 2L), .Label = c("", "BM", "HB", "HFA", "HFZ", "HM", 
"HNA", "HNFA", "HNFZ", "HNZ", "NEA", "NEZ", "NWA", "NWZ", "NZ", 
"SA", "SEA", "SEZ", "SWA", "SWZ", "SZ", "TB", "TM", "TRM", "TRW", 
"U", "WA", "WS", "WW", "WZ"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("data", 
"gwl"), row.names = 2546:2555, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Has the data already been read in? Can you give us a bit more indication of what you're actually working with.

Comment: If you have R read the vector elements between quotes, like c("BM",..., "NA",...), it will treat NA as a character or factor. I second Ananda, please provide us with more info as to how you're feeding this information to R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `factor` will accept `NA` if you introduce it as a `character`.

```
levels(df$gwl) <- c(levels(df$gwl), "NA")
df$gwl[is.na(df$gwl)] <- as.factor("NA")
```

Testing it out:

```
> table(is.na(df$gwl))

FALSE 
   56 
> table(df$gwl=="NA")

FALSE  TRUE 
   55     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Read `?factor`

If you need to replace NA values in character vectors in R do this:

```
 vec[is.na(vec)] <- "NA"
```

It's a bit more complicated in your case since it's a factor and in that case SeñorO's answer is on point as far as adding an "NA" level, although I don't think the `as.factor` function is needed. The important point to understand is that "NA" is not the same as `NA_character_`.

At the time of data entry you should have used colClasses=c("POSIXct", character") and that way you would not have the `POSIXlt` column. That will cause you difficult to understand errors. You should avoid using `POSIXlt` as data.frame column class.